# On Excel is it possible to apply a certain formula after a new date is written on another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to apply this formula `=SUMIFS(K:K;A:A;A3)` on a cell on a column only after a change in the date for example:

[image]

On this image the 14/12 a sum is calculated 2 times while I would love it if only on sum would calculate for each day. Is this possible maybe add a check weather whats MAX day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A3;A3)-COUNTIF(A:A;A3)=0;SUMIFS(K:K;A:A;A3);"")` in the same row # as `A3`

The 1st countif is a counter from the first row up to the current row meeting the condition.
The 2nd countif is a counter of total occurances of the condition.
If 1st minus 2nd equals 0 it'll show your sumif formula, else it shows blank.

Comment: Thank you it works, but can I apply this to all other new dates ? Apply it to the whole column?

Comment: Maybe add a reference to the current cell and modify this sentence?

Comment: Just drag down the formula from A3 to where you like. If you have office 365 you can replace `A3` for `@A:A`

Comment: Thank you very much, still learning ! So basically your formula here, is checking the difference from A$1 which is ehm always the starting cell ? and the current cell (A3)  and then I cant understand the 2nd countif but the whole picture is that when the 2 dates differ.

Comment: The `$` is locking the row number to not change if you drag the formula. (Adding a `$` prior to the column letter would lock the column to not change if dragged to the left/right.)

Comment: Explanation of the two countifs is added to the answer (which can be marked as answered if accepted)

Comment: Yeap totally deserved as anwer, sorry for late response still getting used to things.